# Search from Solr 4.4 to include Alfresco Solr 1.4

Tags: solr, lucene, alfresco, solrj

I have an application which is using Solr 4.4 for search,  Solr 4.4, has a core pointing to database [db1] and I am using JSon at the UI.
Now, in addition, I would like my application to search against Alfresco, which is Internally using Solr 1.4.
What is the preferred approach in getting this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't access Alfresco's Solr directly, why?:
- Alfresco uses some specific query parameters (fq's) to respect permissions
- Alfresco has his one Query Syntax & Query Handler to handle their dynamic data model

So the way to go is to use the existing REST or CMIS APIs or to write your own Alfresco WebScript to execute the search & just consume this REST API in your search app.

more on Alfresco's search syntax:

- http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/rm-searchsyntax-intro.html